# Split and merge outputs parallel

Tags: python, merge, split, output

55=22395|1007=BTCUSD|1008=3|55=22396|1007=BTCEUR|1008=2|55=22397|1007=ETHUSD|1008=3|55=22398|1007=ETHEUR|1008=3|55=20009|1007=TELENET GROUP|1008=2|55=20011|1007=MAGNEGAS CORP|1008=2|55=20012|1007=CALUMET SPEC PRDCTS|1008=2|55=20013|1007=CBOE HLDG INC|1008=2|55=20014|1007=ELECTRONIC ARTS INC|1008=2|55=20015|1007=EXPRESS SCRIPTS INC|1008=2|55=20016|1007=ADVANCE AUTO PARTS|1008=2|55=20017|1007=CHINA FUND INC|

i have request response that appear at terminal like this.

there is a pattern 55=id | 1007=symbol
example : 55=22395|1007=BTCUSD

i want to export this data to use it later on creating the order at this way :
BTCUSD = 22395

any help?

Comment: Oops! Looks like you forgot to post the code that troubling you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to parse the string:

```py
import re

s = """55=22395|1007=BTCUSD|1008=3|55=22396|1007=BTCEUR|1008=2|55=22397|1007=ETHUSD|1008=3|55=22398|1007=ETHEUR|1008=3|55=20009|1007=TELENET GROUP|1008=2|55=20011|1007=MAGNEGAS CORP|1008=2|55=20012|1007=CALUMET SPEC PRDCTS|1008=2|55=20013|1007=CBOE HLDG INC|1008=2|55=20014|1007=ELECTRONIC ARTS INC|1008=2|55=20015|1007=EXPRESS SCRIPTS INC|1008=2|55=20016|1007=ADVANCE AUTO PARTS|1008=2|55=20017|1007=CHINA FUND INC|"""

for id_, symbol in re.findall(r"\b55=(\d+)\|\d+=([^|]+)", s):
    print(f"{symbol:<30} {id_}")
```

Prints:

```
BTCUSD                         22395
BTCEUR                         22396
ETHUSD                         22397
ETHEUR                         22398
TELENET GROUP                  20009
MAGNEGAS CORP                  20011
CALUMET SPEC PRDCTS            20012
CBOE HLDG INC                  20013
ELECTRONIC ARTS INC            20014
EXPRESS SCRIPTS INC            20015
ADVANCE AUTO PARTS             20016
CHINA FUND INC                 20017
```